# Cleaning database after Node.js test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing

Previously, I used Django (Python). In tests creating new lines in database, but after tests new lines automatically delete. Is there a Node.js test framework that automatially clean test line and tables?

Comment: Using a real database connection in your unit tests is generally frowned upon, it's better to mock your database connection. Now, on to your question: you can add the rows you added to the database to an array and loop through that  array to delete the rows when you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into using something like [**`mochajs`**](https://mochajs.org/). Mocha exposes several [hooks](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) to aid build up and teardown for tests. There are many testing frameworks but, I've found mocha to be one of the best, especially when coupled with assertion libraries like [**`chaijs`**](http://chaijs.com/)

Your tests could then be structured similar to the following:

```
describe('My Database Test', function() {
  before(function() {
    // create test table or test records
  });

  after(function() {
    // delete test table or remove test records
  });

  it('should insert new records', function() {
    // insert some test rows
  })
});
```